# Erro no arquivo project.json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou com um erro em meu projeto, ele apareceu depois que adicionei `Entity Framework` ao meu projeto!
Esse erro persiste na linha 21 do arquivo `project.json`.
Estou usando Visual Studio 2015.

A descrição exata do erro é:

> "The dependency EntityFramework 6.1.3 in project foo bar does not
>   support framework .NETPlatform,Version=v5.4"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleta a linha "net451": { } do global.json, se tiver "dotnet5.4", vc muda pra "net451".